# How to show article link and sub-feed link in an RSS feed?

Tags: asp.net, rss

I'm working on some RSS feeds for a custom task system we have.  The main feed will show a list of tasks assigned to the current user.  The link attribute for each task returned points to the web page for that task.  However, tasks themselves have an RSS feed for updates, and I want to be able to provide a link for that RSS feed with the main feed as well.  How can I do both?

The solution I'm thinking of right now is setting the article's `title` attribute to include an `<a href="..."` link to the actual article, and the it's `link` attribute to be a link to the feed (or vice versa).  However, I'm not sure that will work well since most readers display the title as linking to the link (if that makes any sense to you).

Also, is this something that's supported natively by atom?

Answer (score 1):

Make the content of each item in the original RSS feed HTML.  (I believe you'll have to CDATA escape the block).  Within this content put a hyperlink to the updates feed RSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add it to the entry summary as links?

Comment: I'm kinda hoping to get some "native" support for it.  But I don't really expect to find any.

Comment: It's not in the spec http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html 
You could make an extension, but it depends what for do you need it.